# Inline script elements in an AJAX response applied to the DOM - Do they execute in a child window context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am working on a bug, where there is a request made and then an updated view is returned with an inline script block to update some of the view. I was getting an odd reference error with $ not being defined. After some investigation in chrome, I discovered that in the context that appears to exist at the very instant the reference error occurs there is no $ defined, but window.parent.$ *is defined.*

Method of discovery:
I basically had Chrome break on unhandled errors, which naturally brought me to a callstack of one call that was just the anonymous function. Usually the console seems to use a context consistent with the breakpoint, but in this case I had to use the watch window to see what was defined and what was not. I observe this behavior in all of Firefox, Chrome, and I.E.

The fact that the request is an AJAX request is probably irrelevant. When HTML is appended to an already existing DOM, and it has inline script tags - do these inline script tags execute within their own child window context similar to an iframe?

We are injecting the returned response via jQuery, which I am assuming may be handling the execution. Could jQuery be creating a new child window context?

**In what situations outside of an IFrame is a child window context used?**

Comment: I have had problems with inline scripts in the past, but i can't recreate any of them using a fiddle and just appending elements. I seriously doubt jQuery is creating a child window context to run the script in though. http://jsfiddle.net/gVK9M/ In the core, it is using `.html()` to append then content when using `.load`

Comment: Your right I created a fiddle testing it and it doesn't seem to be exhibiting this behavior. I think I'll change the question to emphasize the last part. I'll update the question after a bit more research into what else might be causing this. Along with your sentiments, I am fairly certain it is something with the inline scripts.

Comment: I usually solve this by separating the scripts from the html, appending the html directly, then appending the scripts. To do this, you use regexp to replace <script> and </script> with <div class="script"> and </div>, then parse it into a fragment `var frag = $(thehtml)`, detach and store the scripts `var scripts = frag.find(".script").detach()`, append the html, then append the scripts. By separating them, you ensure that they run in the order you want them to.

Comment: I could also fix it by just assigning my needed references to the parent windows references if undefined. I just want to know what's happening. In chrome if I take a heap snapshot, I am seeing two Window objects in memory.I am not using IFrames and all three browsers seem to be doing this, so I really am curious where this other window could be coming from. I assumed IFrames were the only thing that would spawn a new window [context].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually did end up being an IFrame. Someone was using a callback within a callback using a "ajaxSubmit" extension which used an IFrame internally. My assumption about IFrames not being used was incorrect.